# Неудачные обновления на локальных машинах

Tags: windows, windows-server, windows-server-2012

У меня новый сервер WSUS, работающий на Windows Server 2012, в списке указана версия 6.2.9200.16384.

Большинство клиентов перечисляют 99% в установленном / неприменимом процентном столбце, однако я получаю сообщения от пользователей о том, что многие обновления не выполняются на стороне клиента. WSUS не сообщает об этом как об обновлениях с ошибками. Глядя на windowsupdate.log на клиентских машинах, я вижу строку:

> 2014-11-21 08: 54: 56: 527 968 ​​1040 Отчет ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ: Ошибка CSerializationHelper :: InitSerialize: 0x80070002

Я также вижу много  успешных установок: Windows успешно установила следующие сообщения об обновлении.

Основная проблема заключается в том, что это приводит к перезагрузке системы несколько раз, так как она выполняет откат неудачных обновлений, при этом некоторые пользователи сообщают, что для входа на их компьютеры потребовалось около часа. Мне нужно видеть эти сбои в консоли управления WSUS. Кто-нибудь видел такое раньше?